# Change TextArea text value(different controllers)

Tags: controller, javafx

Please Help

Here is the screen layout of my project.

[image]

The area with blue background is an FXML file with its own controller and the keyboard area is a different FXML file with a controller of its own. Thw keyboard area appears when I click on the textArea.

My question is, how will I code this scenario:

When I press letter Q on the keyboard, the letter 'Q' will appear on the textArea.

I am having difficulty on it since its from a different controller. Please, I badly need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the controller of the blue area `ControllerA` and `ControllerB` the keybord controller. Let `ControllerA` implement the following `interface`

```
public interface KeyListener {
    /*
     * Used when a character is typed.
     */
    void keyPress(char typedChar);

    /*
     * Used when esc, backspace ... are pressed.
     * Use keycodes from java.awt.event.KeyEvent. 
     */
    void keyPress(int vkCode);
}
```

Instead of the keys in java.awt.event.KeyEvent you can use other encodings of course.

Now add a the following code to `ControllerB`:

```
private KeyListener keyListener;

public void setKeyListener(KeyListener keyListener) {
    this.keyListener = keyListener;
}
```

The code where you add the keyboard in `ControllerA` should look like this:

```
//...
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
Pane keyboardPane = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().
                    getResource("YourKeyboardLayout.fxml").openStream());
ControllerB keyboardController = (ControllerB) fxmlLoader.getController();
keyboardController.setKeyListener(this);
//...
```

Now all you have to do is implement the functions of `KeyListener` to adjust the text in the textfield and call the right function of `keyListener` every time a keyboard key is pressed.